# How to update C# Uri Segment?

Tags: c#, url, .net-core

I have a Uri with a URL in the format:  /Review/{product name}/{id}

I'd like to update segment product name like:

```
uri.Segments[2] = product.UrlFriendlyProductName;
```

when I execute the above code, the Uri doesn't update. Any Suggestions?

Comment: The `Segments` property returns new array of strings and you just updating that array without modyfing actual Uri object instance (which is immutable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Uri` class is immutable in a sense that you cannot modify it via public interface. `Segments` basically just splits `Path` by '/' and returns that. To edit `Uri` you can use `UriBuilder` class (which still doesn't modify original, but creates a modified copy). But it doesn't contain convenient `Segments` property, so you have to split yourself. For example:

```
var url = new Uri("http://something/Review/name/1");
var builder = new UriBuilder(url);
// extract segments from path
var segments = builder.Path.Split('/');
// modify
segments[2] = "bla";
// combine back
builder.Path = String.Join('/', segments);
// modified uri
var result = builder.Uri;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UriTemplate` class could be useful for you, but it is not available in .NET Core.

Try maybe [Tavis.UriTemplates](https://github.com/tavis-software/Tavis.UriTemplates) library.